# $2^{nd}$ countable implies separable

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I was looking at this proof that $2^{nd}$ countable implies separable. Could someone clarify if my understanding is correct?

Suppose $X$ is $2^{nd}$ countable having countable basis $\beta=\{B_i|i \in \mathbb{N}\}$. For each $B_i \neq \varnothing$ let $b_i$ be an element of $B_i$ and let $Z$ be the set of all such $b_i$. Then $Z$ is countable. If $V \in \tau$ then $B_i \subset V$ for some $i$ and so $b_i \in V$ thus $V \cap Z \neq \varnothing$. So $Z$ is dense in $Z$ and $X$ is separable.

So in this proof, they basically take a countable basis, choose one point $b_i$ in each basis element in the collection, and form the set $Z$ of all of these individual points coming from exactly one basis element? Then $V \in \tau \implies B_i \subset V$ for some $i$. And this follows from the definition of a basis condition that for each open set $U \in \tau$ and $x \in U$, there is a $B \in \beta$ such that $x \in B  \subset U$? So each open set contains at least one of the $b_i's$ and so each open set intersects $Z$?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is in essence the argument. Minor nitpick: we need a *non-empty* open subset $U$ and so there is some $x\in U$ and only then can we say that there is a basic open $B_i$ such that $x \in B_i \subseteq U$ and then $b_i \in U\cap Z \neq \emptyset$ shows $U$ intersects $Z$ so $Z$ is dense.

That $Z$ is (at most) countable might need an appeal to a theorem too, plus the (unavoidable) use of Countable Choice is swept under the rug somewhat. At least acknowledge the fact.